# Having html code editor like features too in php perspective in eclipse

Tags: javascript, php, html, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I am developing php websites in Eclipse IDE but when i edit codes in php perspective in eclipse i see while i type php codes, predefined php codes coming up.But when i write html codes like `"<div style="` all the html styles not coming up as normally happens in other html editor like dreamweaver. It's quite a bit of deficiency when doing web development mixing php and html codes as usual.So Is there any way in eclipse that auto complete html codes comes up while typing else it's quite difficult to write all the styles of a html tag because i can't remember all the styles and attributes of html tags!!.
I tried this way to narrow the problems -

```
1.Installed web tools platform in eclipse and saw that there is new perspective "web"(or others?) and switching to it and while typing "<div style=" i see styles coming up as automatically to select but then after selection, it's not coming for next style typing !,and not efficient, completely annoying.
```

So please sort it out for me suggesting if any fruitful softwares i can install in eclipse editor which brings that editor like features for html codes as occurs while typing php codes in php perspective.If there is other perspectives which allows this auto completion for php and html and even javascripts codes.

Answer (score 0):

The perspective has nothing to do with this, it only controls the view layout and which actions are enabled by default--and clearly you are able to trigger content assist. This looks more like an issue with the editor itself. Depending on which version you're using, be sure to try the latest. If it's still a problem, report it as a bug (this works in the HTML Editor after all).

Comment: It's very poor thing when we talk about any specific editor there must be at least embedded html editor available like visual studio which serves mainly for c# but as well as html too as html is the underlying codes for web pages.So In a nutshell, there is no html code auto completion feature in eclipse and it's a bug?